# login to the web site event using java

Tags: java, authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

i am trying to login to the site pragmatically using HttpClient like the following:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class HttpClientWebAPITest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/login.jsp");

    try {

      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", "mayank"));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", "hexgen"));

      post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

      String line = "";
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        if (line.startsWith("Auth=")) {
          String key = line.substring(5);
          System.out.println("key : hexgen : "+key);
          // Do something with the key
        }

      } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

this one just prints the login page but i want to login to the system and set JSESSIONID and

would like to check whether the authentication happened correctly.

Please help me to resolve this.

Best Regards
Anto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably need to post credentials to another URL to log in. `http://localhost:8080/login.jsp` is just the address of the login page. Look for a `form` in that jsp file that should have an `action` attribute with the address of the login action. Something like:

```
<form action="j_spring_security_check" method="post">
```

Then target your request to that URL (`http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check`).